# How to run all test cases even if one test case fails

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-testing

```
func Test_something(t *testing.T) {
    // TEST CASE1: pass an array 
      // some logic here

    // TEST CASE2: pass an EMPTY array --> this will cause test to fail
      // some logic here

    // TEST CASE3: pass something else 
      // some logic here
```

I am writing some unit tests but I am not sure if it's possible to run a test `Test_something` that has several test cases without stopping the execution of other test cases if one fails. Or does it even make sense?

In console I would like to see something like this.

```
TESTCASE1: SUCCESS <message>
TESTCASE2: FAIL <message>
TESTCASE3: SUCCESS <message>
```

At the moment I get something like this:

```
TESTCASE1: SUCCESS <message>
TESTCASE2: FAIL <message>
```

It will naturally stop executing after `TESTCASE2` fails.

Comment: I have not used GO language yet but other languages have one function for one test case.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your test function. Specially the assertion of the test steps is interesting.

Comment: You can achieve that with subtests; see https://go.dev/blog/subtests#table-driven-tests-using-subtests

Comment: When you have only one function and run log.fatal() or a similar function then it will abort in GO's native Unit Test enviroment

Comment: can you provide content of you test case 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subtest with the help of the `testing.T.Run` function. It allows to gather several test cases together and have separate status for each of them.

```golang
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("first test case", func(t *testing.T) {
        // implement your first test case here
    })
    t.Run("second test case", func(t *testing.T) {
        // implement your second test case here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with `t *testing.T` you may call:

- `t.Errorf(...)`: it will not stop next tests.
- `t.Fatalf(...)`: it will stop next tests.

See [official doc](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Errorf).